# Probability of a die

Tags: probability

I am unsure about how to do this problem.

A die has faces 1 to 6 and is weighted so that the probability of throwing $n$ in a single throw is proportional to $n$ ($n = 1,2,3,4,5,6$); that is, equals $\lambda n$; that is, equals to $\lambda n$;  for some constant $n$.

I know that the sum of probabilities must equal 1. I think I should add up all the values of $n$ together 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21. Then I divide 21 by 6 since there are 6 possible outcomes to get my constant $\frac{7}{2}$. But that can't be right because that's saying the sum all of the probabilities is 21, but it should be 1! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It should be "for some constant $\lambda$ at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: Why you want the "constant" if the die is weighted? Anyway you must divide by 21 to have all relative to 1 my friend ;), so divide $7/2$ by 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^6\lambda n=1,
$$
or 
$$
\lambda\sum_{n=1}^6n=1,
$$
or 
$$
21\lambda=1,
$$
so $\lambda=\frac{1}{21}$. With this, your probability of rolling say a $4$ would be $\frac{4}{21}$.